# Search function using twig in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I want to create a simple search function.

Search form

```
<form class="pull-right hidden" role="search" id="nav-search-form" method="post" action="{{ path('_search') }}">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" name ="search">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"></button>
          </span>
        </div>
      </form>
```

In my DefaultController. I have a search function

```
public function searchAction(){
       $request = $this->getRequest();
       $data =$request->request->all();


       $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
       $query = $em->createQuery(
        'SELECT p.type, p.id
        FROM FooTransBundle:Trans p
        WHERE p.type LIKE :data')
       ->setParameter('data',$data['search']);


    $res = $query->getResult();

    return $this->render('FooTransBundle:Default:search.html.twig', array(
        'res' => $res));
```

}

And after I run that I got an error

Notice: Undefined index: search in C:\xampp\htdocs\Sample\src\Foo\TransBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line 96

It is in the line ->setParameter('data',$data['search']); of my Controller

Can someone help me. I am very new to symfony.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Error says php can't access to $data['search'] because it is undefined. Try to var_dump the content of $data before your query that might help you figure out its type and see how to access it's content.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
public function searchAction(){
   $request = $this->getRequest();
   $data = $request->request->get('search');


   $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
   $query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT p FROM FooTransBundle:Suplier p
    WHERE p.name LIKE :data')
   ->setParameter('data',$data);


$res = $query->getResult();

return $this->render('FooTransBundle:Default:search.html.twig', array(
    'res' => $res));
```

Comment: Thank you it's now running :) But can you help me on how I will be able to see the output? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: In your twig file simply just type like ..{% for r in res %}{{ r.entityAttribute }} .. i.e. {{ r.id }}, {{ r.type }}{% endfor %} etc.., also see my updated answer ..

Comment: I have a one last question, is it possible that I can search according to all the data present in the database not just by it's type as seen in WHERE p.type LIKE :data') this part of the code?

Comment: ya, exactly u can do , just as "WHERE p.anotherEntityFieldName LIKE :data" .. where anotherEntityFieldName is any field name of your entity class like type , name , etc ..

Comment: Can you give a sample statement? I have a Supplier table with id and name as attribute. Should I write like this -> WHERE p.name LIKE :data directly? Where name is an attribute of the the Supplier table.

Comment: again see my above answer in which i have updated my answer as per your requirement ...; basically changed p.ype to p.name ..and also the table name